# building android UI forms using xml data

Tags: android, xml, architecture

I'm thinking of creating User Input(UI) forms for my android application using an XML schema definition. Essentially the users would write an xml file with data and layout elements embedded in to it and would see a new form created when deploy it to my android application. I choose this approach because all my UI forms are mapped to XML files to store the user entered data. Does anybody if there is any such framework available? Or do you see any issues with my idea to resolve the problem in hand ?

Comment: Why to reinvent the wheel? Android already provides UI controls and forms in form of XML. Or I did not understand you well?

Comment: I already an xml schema that I use in the application to map to the input fields on UI forms. I wanted to extend the existing schema to create forms. May be I should think of creating XML for android from what I have.